# In some cases is "そうですね" synonymous with "そうです"?

Tags: nuances, sentence-final-particles, particle-ね

I understand that "そうですね" is use to express agreement with the listener meaning something like "isn't it?"

But I saw some sentences where its meanings seem to be "That's right" or "Yes" and it's not about agreement but seems closer to "そうです" on [this site](https://nihongomaster.com/japanese/dictionary/word/95024/soudesune),
such as

> 1. そうですね。下手にでてばかりもなんだし。かつ、倫理的ですね。
>    That's right. It's written in an unassuming fashion, and it's an ethical standpoint as well.

> 2. そうですね。毎日練習する事が必要ですよ。
>    Yes, you need to practice every day.

Or [this conversation](https://web.archive.org/web/20090804085417/http://webmagazine.gentosha.co.jp/B-TEAM/vol208_special_qanda.html) which I found.

> Q.15 「ふたりはプリキュア」から「ふたりはプリキュアMaxHeart」になった時には進級がありましたが、「Yes！プリキュア5」から「Yes！プリキュア5GoGo」で進級がなかったのは、こまち、かれんが卒業してしまうからでしょうか？

> A. そうですね、高校生になるとか、学年が変わるということがやっぱり気にはなりました。番組を続ける議論のなかでは3年生は卒業させて新しいプリキュアを入れるべきだという話もありましたが、「プリキュア5」というのはこの5人以外あり得ない、この5人であるからこそ「プリキュア5」なんだよっていうことを言い続けた結果ああなりました。

In these examples "そうですね"'s meaning isn't agreement but synonymous with "そうです". I am not sure about the last conversation. I want to know if I can use "そうですね" instead of "そうです" in some situations.

Comment: This may be related [56698/reason-for-the-ね-in-いいですね](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56698/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, そうですね can mean "Yes" or "That's correct". This ね is a sentence-end/filler particle used simply to make the sentence sound friendlier. It's fine to use ね with a piece of information new to the listener.

- 「テストはいつですか？」「明日ですね。」
  "When is the test?" "Tomorrow."
- 「これはカツカレーですか？」「違いますね。」
  "Is this katsu-curry?" "No it isn't."

Note that そうですね also works as a [filler to buy time](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16030/5010) ("Let's see", "Well", "Um"). It's perfectly fine to respond to a wh-question with そうですね.

Comment: What about third example which conversation? "そうですね" in this case synonym "そうです" too?

Comment: @natta23699 Indeed the third example may be a bit different. そうです is always explicit "Yes that's correct", but this そうですね can be closer to "Well, ..." or "Um, yeah, ...".